# Class not found exception in Android code

Tags: android

This is my code:

```
package com.example.testcode;

import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.content.CursorLoader;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener;


public class TestAndActivity extends ListFragment implements OnQueryTextListener,
        LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {







    // This is the Adapter being used to display the list's data.
    SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;

    // If non-null, this is the current filter the user has provided.
    String mCurFilter;




    @Override
    public void  onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super .onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        // Give some text to display if there is no data.  In a real
        // application this would come from a resource.
        setEmptyText("No phone numbers");

        // We have a menu item to show in action bar.
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        // Create an empty adapter we will use to display the loaded data.
        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, null,
                new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTACT_STATUS },
                new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 }, 0);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);

        // Start out with a progress indicator.
        setListShown(false);

        // Prepare the loader.  Either re-connect with an existing one,
        // or start a new one.
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

    @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
 // Inflate the layout for this fragment 
        final View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false); return contentView; }


    @Override public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // Place an action bar item for searching.
        MenuItem item = menu.add("Search");
        //item.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search);
        item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
        SearchView sv = new SearchView(getActivity());
        sv.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        item.setActionView(sv);
    }

    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        // Called when the action bar search text has changed.  Update
        // the search filter, and restart the loader to do a new query
        // with this filter.
        mCurFilter = !TextUtils.isEmpty(newText) ? newText : null;
        getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);
        return true;
    }

    @Override public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        // Don't care about this.
        return true;
    }

    @Override public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // Insert desired behavior here.


    }

    // These are the Contacts rows that we will retrieve.
    static final String[] CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION = new String[] {
        ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTACT_STATUS,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTACT_PRESENCE,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY,
    };

    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        // This is called when a new Loader needs to be created.  This
        // sample only has one Loader, so we don't care about the ID.
        // First, pick the base URI to use depending on whether we are
        // currently filtering.
        Uri baseUri;
        if (mCurFilter != null) {
            baseUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
                    Uri.encode(mCurFilter));
        } else {
            baseUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        }

        // Now create and return a CursorLoader that will take care of
        // creating a Cursor for the data being displayed.
        String select = "((" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " NOTNULL) AND ("
                + ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1) AND ("
                + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " != '' ))";
        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), baseUri,
                CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION, select, null,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
    }

    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        // Swap the new cursor in.  (The framework will take care of closing the
        // old cursor once we return.)
        mAdapter.swapCursor(data);

        // The list should now be shown.
        if (isResumed()) {
            setListShown(true);
        } else {
            setListShownNoAnimation(true);
        }
    }

    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        // This is called when the last Cursor provided to onLoadFinished()
        // above is about to be closed.  We need to make sure we are no
        // longer using it.
        mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
}
**strong text**
```

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment class="com.example.testcode.TestAndActivity"
            android:id="@+id/titles" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/details" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my manifest:

```
**<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testcode"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

    <application

        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

         <activity android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:name="android.app.TestAndActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>**
```

The error I get is this:

```
   01-24 22:50:49.751: E/AndroidRuntime(1416): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.app.TestAndActivity
```

I am using fragments and loaders for the first time. Though, code has no errors, I believe I got it wrong in both the manifest and layout.

Can anyone tell me where I went wrong?
 **

> Edit:

**

```
If I change android.app.TestAndActivity to .TestAndActivity, I get the error can not cast TestAndActivity to android.app.
```

Comment: what is the JDK version you are using ?

Comment: I use google apis. Android 4.03.

Comment: Where is your `R.layout.fragment_layout`

Comment: First read this `http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `Fragment` not the `Activity` and define the `Fragment` as `Activity` in manifest.
`Fragment` should be inside an `Activity`. Create another `Activity`, put the `Fragment` in their and define the `Activity` Name in Manifest.

Comment: Edited the question. Do check.

Comment: Read this - `http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html`

Answer (score 1):

Activity not defined with correct package name. It should be `com.example.testcode.TestAndActivity`

Answer (score 0):

change `android:name="android.app.TestAndActivity"` to `android:name=".TestAndActivity"`

your package declaration is `package com.example.testcode;` and your `TestAndActivity` is under this package then why are you using `android.app` in your activity declaration.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

this is your line in AndroidmainFest.xml

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:name="android.app.TestAndActivity">
```

Change it according below code,

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:name="com.example.testcode.TestAndActivity">
```

Comment: Edited the question. Do check.